# OpenAI API error: "This is a chat model and not supported in the v1/completions endpoint"

Tags: python, discord, openai-api, chatgpt-api

```
import discord
import openai
import os


openai.api_key = os.environ.get("OPENAI_API_KEY")

#Specify the intent
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

#Create Client
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

async def generate_response(message):
    prompt = f"{message.author.name}: {message.content}\nAI:"
    response = openai.Completion.create(
        engine="gpt-3.5-turbo",
        prompt=prompt,
        max_tokens=1024,
        n=1,
        stop=None,
        temperature=0.5,
    )
    return response.choices[0].text.strip()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"We have logged in as {client.user}")
    
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    response = await generate_response(message)
    await message.channel.send(response)

discord_token = 'DiscordToken'


client.start(discord_token)
```

I try to use diferent way to access the API key, including adding to enviroment variables.

What else can I try or where I'm going wrong, pretty new to programming.
Error message:

> openai.error.AuthenticationError: No API key provided. You can set your API key in code using 'openai.api_key = ', or you can set the environment variable OPENAI_API_KEY=). If your API key is stored in a file, you can point the openai module at it with 'openai.api_key_path = '. You can generate API keys in the OpenAI web interface. See https://onboard.openai.com for details, or email support@openai.com if you have any questions.

---

**EDIT**

I solved "No API key provided" error. Now I get the following error message:

> openai.error.InvalidRequestError: This is a chat model and not
> supported in the v1/completions endpoint. Did you mean to use
> v1/chat/completions?

Comment: It seems like environment variable `OPENAI_API_KEY` is not properly set. Could you try to `print(os.environ.get("OPENAI_API_KEY"))` and see if an API key appears?

Comment: You probably want to use [`python-dotenv`](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/) to populate your dictionary

Comment: Thank you using dotenv work, now Im getting the next error message 
"openai.error.InvalidRequestError: This is a chat model and not supported in the v1/completions endpoint. Did you mean to use v1/chat/completions?"

Im using gpt-3.5-turbo

Comment: It's not kosher to edit your question to make it a completely different question after it has an answer; the appropriate thing past that point is to ask a new, separate question.

Comment: i ran into the An error occurred: This is a chat model and not supported in the v1/completions endpoint. Did you mean to use v1/chat/completions? i resolved it using  text-davinci-003 as the model

Answer (score 28):

### Regarding `openai.error.InvalidRequestError: This is a chat model and not supported in the v1/completions endpoint`

The code you posted above would work immediately if you change just one thing: `gpt-3.5-turbo` to `text-davinci-003`. This gives you an answer as to why you're getting this error. It's because you used the code that works with the GPT-3 API endpoint, but wanted to use the GPT-3.5 model (i.e., `gpt-3.5-turbo`). See [model endpoint compatibility](https://platform.openai.com/docs/models/model-endpoint-compatibility).

| API endpoint | Model group | Model name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| /v1/chat/completions | • GPT-4 • GPT-3.5 | • `gpt-4` and dated model releases • `gpt-4-32k` and dated model releases • `gpt-4-1106-preview` • `gpt-4-vision-preview` • `gpt-3.5-turbo` and dated model releases • `gpt-3.5-turbo-16k` and dated model releases • fine-tuned versions of `gpt-3.5-turbo` |
| /v1/completions (Legacy) | • GPT-3.5 • GPT base | • `gpt-3.5-turbo-instruct` • `babbage-002` • `davinci-002` |
| /v1/assistants |  | All models except `gpt-3.5-turbo-0301` supported. Retrieval tool requires `gpt-4-1106-preview` or `gpt-3.5-turbo-1106`. |
| /v1/audio/transcriptions | Whisper | • `whisper-1` |
| /v1/audio/translations | Whisper | • `whisper-1` |
| /v1/audio/speech | TTS | • `tts-1` • `tts-1-hd` |
| /v1/fine_tuning/jobs | • GPT-3.5 • GPT base | • `gpt-3.5-turbo` • `babbage-002` • `davinci-002` |
| /v1/embeddings | Embeddings | • `text-embedding-ada-002` |
| /v1/moderations | Moderations | • `text-moderation-stable` • `text-moderation-latest` |

**If you want to use the `gpt-3.5-turbo` model, then you need to write the code that works with the GPT-3.5 API endpoint (i.e., the [Chat Completions API](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/text-generation/chat-completions-api) endpoint).**

As you can see in the table above, there are API endpoints listed. If you're using the OpenAI package (like you are), then you need to use the appropriate method name. See the table below.

*Note: Pay attention, because you have to use the method name that is compatible with your OpenAI SDK version.*

| API endpoint | Python SDK <`v1` method name | Python SDK `v1` method name | Node.js SDK `v3` method name | Node.js SDK `v4` method name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| /v1/chat/completions | openai.ChatCompletion.create | openai.chat.completions.create | openai.createChatCompletion | openai.chat.completions.create |
| /v1/completions (Legacy) | openai.Completion.create | openai.completions.create | openai.createCompletion | openai.completions.create |
| /v1/assistants | / | openai.beta.assistants.create | / | openai.beta.assistants.create |
| /v1/audio/transcriptions | openai.Audio.transcribe | openai.audio.transcriptions.create | openai.createTranscription | openai.audio.transcriptions.create |
| /v1/audio/translations | openai.Audio.translate | openai.audio.translations.create | openai.createTranslation | openai.audio.translations.create |
| /v1/audio/speech | / | openai.audio.speech.create | / | openai.audio.speech.create |
| /v1/fine_tuning/jobs | / | openai.fine_tuning.jobs.create | / | openai.fineTuning.jobs.create |
| /v1/embeddings | openai.Embedding.create | openai.embeddings.create | openai.createEmbedding | openai.embeddings.create |
| /v1/moderations | openai.Moderation.create | openai.moderations.create | openai.createModeration | openai.moderations.create |

You need to adjust the whole code. See comments in the working example below.

##### Python SDK `v1` working example for the `gpt-3.5-turbo` model (i.e., [Chat Completions API](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/text-generation/chat-completions-api))

If you run `test.py`, the OpenAI API will return the following completion:

> Hello there! How can I assist you today?

**test.py**

```
import os
from openai import OpenAI
client = OpenAI()
OpenAI.api_key = os.getenv('OPENAI_API_KEY')

completion = client.chat.completions.create( # Change the method name
  model = 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
  messages = [ # Change the prompt parameter to messages parameter
    {'role': 'user', 'content': 'Hello!'}
  ],
  temperature = 0  
)

print(completion.choices[0].message.content) # Change message content extraction
```

### Regarding `openai.error.AuthenticationError: No API key provided`

Change this...

```
openai.api_key = os.environ.get('OPENAI_API_KEY')
```

...to this.

```
openai.api_key = os.getenv('OPENAI_API_KEY')
```

Comment: can you explain more about the difference between the assistant and the chat completions?
i don't understand if i can use the chat completions if my application doesn't require chat capabilities but simply language understanding. 
and what should i use for the latest llm capabilities that are not for chat? 
also, can you refer to langchain in your answers?
thanks!

Comment: @enter_thevoid The [Assistants API](https://platform.openai.com/docs/assistants/overview/agents) elevates OpenAI models by helping them with different [tools](https://platform.openai.com/docs/assistants/tools/tools-beta) (e.g., the Code Interpreter tool). If your app doesn't require chat functionality, I would suggest you use one of the [GPT base models](https://platform.openai.com/docs/models/gpt-base).

Answer (score 3):

Change this:

```
from langchain.llms import OpenAI
llm = OpenAI(temperature=0, max_tokens=1000)
```

To this:

```
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
llm = ChatOpenAI(temperature=0, model="gpt-3.5-turbo-0613", max_tokens=1000)
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

these are model endpoint for different tasks that are currently used by OPENAI.

You used  engine="gpt-3.5-turbo" in Completions. instead use openai.ChatCompletion.create. or you change to other completion models.

You can find more here.[model-endpoint-compatibility](https://platform.openai.com/docs/models/model-endpoint-compatibility)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The model `model = 'gpt-3.5-turbo'` isn't supported with the endpoint `/v1/completions`.
It needs `/v1/chat/completions` endpoint.
Change your code accordingly and it works
let us know if you still have any issues
You can refer to the documentation for all the various endpoints and their respective endpoints
[official documentation](https://platform.openai.com/docs/models/overview)

Comment: https://api.openai.com/v1/completions is what is in the documentation per @mirik's comment

Comment: https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/text-generation/text-generation-models

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't writing a discord bot, but a console terminal application.
They key difference between the GPT3 and gpt-3.5-turbo code are the role assignments.

You can make the AI respond neutral and precise, but you can also make a role-play scenario fitting your setting.

The example is elaborate, but this should provide plenty of material for people encountering the same problems, switching from the old Davinci etc. models to the new system, requiring new syntax to get the code running.

My working cyberpunk-themed example looks something like this:

```
import os
import openai

# Authenticate with OpenAI

os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY") # Remember to export OPENAI_API_KEY="your API key here" in the terminal first. 

# Define a function to prompt the user for input and generate a response
def generate_response(prompt):
    # Call the OpenAI API to generate a response
    response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
        model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
        messages=[{"role": "system", "content":"This is the year 2099.I am a cyberpunk AI. Ask me anything."},{'role': 'user', 'content': prompt}],
        max_tokens=1024,
        n=1,
        temperature=0.5,
        top_p=1,
        frequency_penalty=0.0,
        presence_penalty=0.6,
    )
    # Get the response text from the API response
    response_text = response['choices'][0]['message']['content']

    return response_text

# Start the conversation with the user
print("Welcome to a conversation with a cyberpunk AI in the year 2099!")

# Loop to continue the conversation until the user exits
while True:
    # Prompt the user for input
    prompt = input("You: ")

    # Generate a response to the user input
    response = generate_response(prompt)

    # Print the response
    print("Cyberpunk AI:", response)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty late to this, but had the same problem. Short answer is the easiest thing to do is change your code to this: (this is not the best code; [the space moves fast](https://platform.openai.com/docs/deprecations).)

```
def get_llm_client():
return OpenAI(openai_api_key=os.environ.get(
"OPENAI_API_KEY", "KEYNOTFOUNDSORRYJORDAN"), model="gpt-3.5-turbo-instruct")
def explain_subject(subject):
llm = get_llm_client()
prompt = (
'Explain this subject to me like I'm 5 with a short attention span: \n',

'{subject}',

'PERIODT!'
)
prompt = prompt.format(
subject=subject
)
response = llm.predict(prompt, max_tokens=3000, temperature=0.7, top_p=1,
frequency_penalty=0.5, presence_penalty=0.5, stop=["PERIODT!"])
return response
```

The hardest thing to me seems to be the intracacies of the lanchain/llm space. The biggest difference between the models is whether they are the "simple" ones, (completions i think) or "chat" based models. Depending on which one you are using, they will or will not be compatible with diff langchain methods, and openAI endpoints. [This page](https://platform.openai.com/docs/models/model-endpoint-compatibility) this very helpful for tracking which ones are compatible with what.

The key here is using "gpt-3.5-turbo-instruct" which is the recommended replacement for all "instruct gpt models", including "text-davinci-003"

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

When using the openai version 1.0 client in python, call as follows for the latest chat models:

```py
from openai import OpenAI

client = OpenAI(api_key=openai_key)


completion = client.chat.completions.create(model = 'gpt-3.5-turbo-1106',
  messages = [ # Change the prompt parameter to the messages parameter
    {'role': 'user', 'content': 'Hello!'}
  ],
  temperature = 0  
)

print("ChatGPT Response:", completion.choices[0].message.content)
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following command and it worked:

```
example_gen_chain=QAGenerateChain.from_llm(ChatOpenAI(model='gpt-3.5-turbo-0613'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error and fixed it by downgrading the versions.

```
openai==1.2.0
langchain==0.0.332
```

So in your cmd:-

```
pip uninstall langchain
pip uninstall openai

# then
pip install langchain==0.0.330
pip install openai==0.28.1
```

with the imports

```
# from this
from langchain_openai import OpenAI

# to this
from langchain.llms import OpenAI
```