# Failing to upgrade the OpenAI Node.js SDK from v3 to v4

Tags: angular, openai-api, gpt-3

I'm trying to update my app from Angular 15 and `"openai": "^3.2.1"` to Angular 17 and `"openai": ^4.24.1"`.

I cannot understand what is missing. No errors occurred.

Followed links:

1. https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/text-generation/completions-api
2. https://github.com/openai/openai-node/discussions/217
3. [OpenAI API error: "The model `text-davinci-003` has been deprecated"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77789886/openai-api-error-the-model-text-davinci-003-has-been-deprecated)
4. [OpenAI ChatGPT (GPT-3.5) API error: "This is a chat model and not supported in the v1/completions endpoint"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75774873/openai-chatgpt-gpt-3-5-api-error-this-is-a-chat-model-and-not-supported-in-t)

Old version:

```
import { Configuration, OpenAIApi } from 'openai';
  readonly configuration = new Configuration({
    organization: environment.openAIOrganization,
    apiKey: environment.openAIToken,
  });


  readonly openai = new OpenAIApi(this.configuration);

  //#region -- GENERATE CHATGPT MSG --
  async getDataFromOpenAI(text: string): Promise<any> {
    try {
      const completion = await this.openai.createCompletion({
        model: "text-davinci-003",
        prompt: text,
        temperature: 0.9,
        max_tokens: 62,
      },
        {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            //'baseOptions': 'User-Agent',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + environment.openAIToken,
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
          }
        })

      return completion.data.choices[0].text
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.error('error.message', error);
    }
  }
  //#endregion
```

New version:

```
import OpenAI from 'openai';



 async generateSms() {
    try {
      let completion = await this.openai.completions.create({
        model: 'gpt-3.5-turbo-instruct',
        prompt: 'Create a happy birthday message',
        temperature: 0.5,
      });
      console.log(completion);
      console.log(completion.choices[0].text);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error('generateSms => ', e);      
    }
  }
```

I created a new key but is only returning [null]

Last used in API KEY is updating: **last used 12/jan**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The initialization is different with the OpenAI Node.js SDK `v4` than with `v3`.

If you're using the OpenAI Node.js SDK `v4`, then the following is the correct initialization:

```
const OpenAI = require("openai");

const openai = new OpenAI({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});
```

You did the completion part correctly, as follows:

```
let completion = await this.openai.completions.create({
    model: "gpt-3.5-turbo-instruct",
    prompt: "Say this is a test.",
});
```

Comment: I`m using a normal npm installation npm install --save openai
and update my import now in question. https://github.com/openai/openai-node

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'choices')

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Are you still having problems? Does the `completion.choices[0].text` not work?